# In Java, how can I manipulate a variable instantiated from another class?

Tags: java, instantiation

I am very new to Java and am making a simple application. That consists of two classes, `Computer` and `Player`. In `Player`, I prompt the user to guess a five digit string. In `Computer`, I instantiate the `Player` class as so:

```
Player number = new Player();
number.getGuess();
```

Next, I created a loop to check if the computer and player's numbers match. In order to do this, I need to turn the five digits of the player's number into a integer. Why won't Java let me do:

```
int playerdigit = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i,i+1));
```

It keeps giving me the error that the method .substring isn't defined.
How can I do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to access to `substring` (a method of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class). In the code that you show to us you are trying to access to a method in your class `Player` making reference to the method substring (of the class `String` as I put above) and you should have to make reference to some `String` from your class `Player`. Maybe it could be, supposing that your class `Player` has the name of the player and the number in the game (it's an example), like this:

```
public class Player
{
   int numPlayer;
   String name;
}
```

and with your methods `GET` and `SET` for this attributes:

```
public void setNumPlayer(int numPlayer)
{
   this.numPlayer = numPlayer;
}

public int getNumPlayer()
{
  return numPlayer;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
   this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
   return name;
}
```

You should make reference to the `GET` method that returns your `String` and then you will be able to use `substring` method of `String` class. Something like this:

```
int playerdigit = Integer.parseInt(number.getName().substring(i,i+1));
```

Also, I saw that you are trying to make:

```
number.getGuess();
```

Maybe what you are trying (I don't know that) it's to get a `String` with `getGuess` method. Then you should do that:

```
String guess = number.getGuess();
```

to store the value of your `String`.

After, you will be able to make the substring:

```
int playerdigit = Integer.parseInt(guess.substring(i,i+1));
```

I expect it helps to you!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your `Player` class has no method called `substring`. Maybe you're missing some call like `number.getMyStringMember().substring(i,i+1)`?

Answer (score 1):

The 'substring' method is a non-static method of the String class (non-static means that you call the method using an instance of the class rather than using the class name itself). Therefore you want to call this method in the format:
`some_string.substring(start_index, end_index)`, keeping in mind the ending index is not inclusive. In your case, you are trying to call the substring method on a player object (since your 'number' variable is bound to a player object, and the Player class does not have a substring method). Instead, you probably should do the following (which has better naming convention as well since "number" does not refer to a player object):

```
Player p = new Player();
String number = p.getGuess();
```

Then, in your loop, you can do:

```
Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i,i+1));
```

and check each digit individually with your computer's generated number.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think your subconscious made a fake in yourself. `number` should be a `String`, right?